# Why is 50 reputation needed to comment?

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I have noticed that to comment, you need 50 reputation. **Could someone please explain why?** I think it is ridiculous and others (at least one other) shares my thoughts (see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44756/why-were-the-thieves-who-were-crucified-with-jesus-crucified?noredirect=1#comment123884_44756). I am hoping for someone to shed some light on the subject.

Comment: Is there something about the explanation for this in [the tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) that's unclear?

Comment: "**Ask questions, get answers, no distractions** - This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Comment: @bruisedreed It said that 50 rep is required, but I was wondering why.

Comment: As I said in the (now deleted) comment chain linked above, it is primarily to prevent "thanks" and other useless comments from readers who don't know/care how the site works and found a post via an internet search.

Comment: For reference, here is the "official" SE explanation: [short version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71390/301022), [long version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/301022)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a question an answer site, not a discussion forum. A large portion of folks arriving at this site off the Internet are *expecting* a discussion forum and this is a major attitude adjustment they have to get over to use the site effectively. The 50 rep barrier is to make sure that people get off on the right foot and realize right away that the focus here is on question posts and answer posts, not comments. Once they understand how those basic building blocks work and have demonstrated a basic proficiency with them (1 good post or a couple mediocre ones are enough to earn 50 rep) then the feature is added in and we hope they will understand when [not] to use it.

Comment: You can also learn more about the reputation system by going to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation